# Room db with many to many relations : returns single entry on querying for filtered data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I have 3 enitities `Person`, `PersonTagRelation` and `Tag` : Person is related to a tag via many to many relation.
I also have a single dao for having multiple functions for querying db.
Most of the things are working well , but i have this query that is suppose to create a filtered list of users having a particular tag , which doesn't sem to work.
For eg, if there are 3 persons `A`,`B`,`C` with corresponding taglist as `[ai,ml]`,`[ai]`,`[flutter]` respectively. then my query is supposed to return
`[A,B]` when passed the tag `ai`. But it is returning only `[A]`.
 Please checkout the following code and let me know where i went wrong:

Person.class

```
@Entity()
public class Person {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long presonID;
    private String personName;
...
}
```

Tag.class

```
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long tagID;
    private String tagValue;
    ...
}
```

PersonTagRelation.class

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"personTagIDForPerson","personTagIDForTag"},
        foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Person.class, parentColumns = "presonID", childColumns = "personTagIDForPerson"),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Tag.class, parentColumns = "tagID", childColumns = "personTagIDForTag"),
})
public class PersonTagRelation {
   private long personTagIDForPerson, personTagIDForTag;
   ...
   }
```

PersonDao.class

```
@Dao
public abstract class PersonDao {
    @Insert abstract void insertNewPerson(Person p);
    @Insert abstract void insertNewTag(Tag t);
    @Insert abstract void insertNewRelation(PersonTagRelation relation);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Person ORDER BY presonID DESC")
    abstract List<Person> getAllPersons();

    @Query("SELECT tagID FROM Tag WHERE tagValue=:tag ORDER BY tagID DESC")
    abstract long getTagIdByTagName(String tag);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Person" +
            " INNER JOIN PersonTagRelation ON Person.presonID=PersonTagRelation.personTagIDForPerson " +
            "WHERE PersonTagRelation.personTagIDForTag=:tagID")
    abstract List<Person> getAllPersonsForTagID(long tagID);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Tag " +
            "INNER JOIN PersonTagRelation ON Tag.tagID=PersonTagRelation.personTagIDForTag " +
            "WHERE PersonTagRelation.personTagIDForPerson=:personID")
    abstract List<Tag> getAllTagsForPerson(long personID);


    @Transaction
    public void insertNewPersonTagData(UiModel model) {
        insertNewPerson(model.getPerson());
        for (Tag t : model.getTags()) {
            insertNewTag(t);
            insertNewRelation(new PersonTagRelation(model.getPerson().getPresonID(), t.getTagID()));
        }
    }
    @Transaction
    public List<UiModel> getFilteredModelList(String tag) {
        List<UiModel> resultlist = new ArrayList<>();
        long tagID = getTagIdByTagName(tag);
        List<Person> filteredPersonList = getAllPersonsForTagID(tagID);

        for (Person p : filteredPersonList) {
            List<Tag> associatedTags = getAllTagsForPerson(p.getPresonID());
            resultlist.add(new UiModel(p, associatedTags));
        }
        return resultlist;
    }

    @Transaction
    public List<UiModel> getAllAsModelList() {
        List<UiModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Person> allpersons = getAllPersons();
        for (Person p : allpersons) {
            List<Tag> associatedTags = getAllTagsForPerson(p.getPresonID());
            modelList.add(new UiModel(p, associatedTags));
        }
        return modelList;
    }
```

UiModel.class

```
public class UiModel {
    private Person person= new Person(System.currentTimeMillis(),"");
    private List<Tag> tagList = new ArrayList<>();

    public UiModel() {
    }
}
```

Picture 1 : the results of `getAllAsModelList()`
picture 2 : the results of `getFilteredModelList()` when `JS` is passed
[image: pic1] [image: pic2]

**Update:**
The test suite provided by @MikeT is very good, but as it turns out the database and the query functions are totally correct. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: I would start by copying the database off of your device or emulator using Android Studio's Device File Explorer. Next, use a SQLite client (e.g., https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to confirm that your database contents are what you expect. Then, use that database client to manually execute your `INNER JOIN` SQL and see if you get the expected results. If you do, then as MikeT suggests, the problem may be in your post-processing in Java. If you do not, then you can play around with the SQL until you find the SELECT statement that gives you what you want, then adjust your DAO to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out , it was my silly ui at fault. I was **generating a new id every time i add a tag, even if its already present**. thus if my DB has the following entries(from what it looks like):

```
Person --- Tags
A      --- ai ,ml
B      --- ml
C      --- flutter
```

it was actually this :

```
id---person     id---tag        id_person-----------id_tag
101 -  A        11 - ai             101      --       11 
102 -  B        12 - ml             101      --       12
103 -  C        13 - ml //! wrong   102      --       13 //wrong!!  
                14 - flutter        103      --       14
```

My ui was not checking weather a tag existed before adding it as new tag. That's why the `getFilteredModelList()` function was not able to generate a list with more than 1 entry. so i ended up writing an extra checker code for that. Also, the dao ended up with the following mini change( an extra onConflict check for all three internal insertion functions):

```
@Dao
public abstract class PersonDao {
    private static final String TAG = "personDao>>";

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract void insertNewPerson(Person... p); 

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract void insertNewTag(Tag... t);          

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract void insertNewRelation(PersonTagRelation... relation);  

    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is how you are processing the UiModel list returned from the **getFilteredModelList** method.

Consider the following methods added for debugging purposes (in this example case, added to MainActivity.java). :-

```
public static void logUiModel(List<UiModel> uiModelList) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (UiModel u: uiModelList) {
        sb.append("\n\tUIModel Person ID = " + String.valueOf(u.getPerson().getPresonID()) + " Person Name = " + u.getPerson().getPersonName());
        for (Tag t: u.getTags()) {
            sb.append("\n\t\tTag ID =" + String.valueOf(t.getTagID()) + " Value = " + t.getTagValue());
        }
    }
    Log.d("UIMODELINFO(LIST)",sb.toString());
}

public static void logUiModel(UiModel uiModel) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("\nUIMODEL Person ID = " +String.valueOf(uiModel.getPerson().getPresonID()) + " Person Name = " + uiModel.getPerson().getPersonName());
    for (Tag t: uiModel.getTags()) {
        sb.append("\n\t\tTag ID =" + String.valueOf(t.getTagID()) + " Value = " + t.getTagValue());
    }
    Log.d("UIMODELINFO",sb.toString());
}

public static void logPersons(List<Person> personList) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("People are :-");
    for (Person p: personList) {
        sb.append("\n\tPerson ID is " + String.valueOf(p.getPresonID()) + " Name is" + p.getPersonName());
    }
    Log.d("PERSONINFO",sb.toString());
}

public static void logTags(List<Tag> tagList) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("Tags are");
    for (Tag t: tagList) {
        sb.append("\n\tTag ID is " + String.valueOf(t.getTagID()) + " Value is " + t.getTagValue());
    }
    Log.d("TAGINFO",sb.toString());
}
```

And the following changes to the **getFilteredModelList** method :-

```
@Transaction
public List<UiModel> getFilteredModelList(String tag) {
    List<UiModel> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    long tagID = getTagIdByTagName(tag);
    Log.d("GETFLTRMDLLST","Processing TAG where value is " + tag + " ID is " + String.valueOf(tagID));
    List<Person> filteredPersonList = getAllPersonsForTagID(tagID);

    for (Person p : filteredPersonList) {
        Log.d("GETFLTRDMDLLST","Persons are :-");
        MainActivity.logPersons(filteredPersonList);
        List<Tag> associatedTags = getAllTagsForPerson(p.getPresonID());
        Log.d("GETFLTRDMDLLST","Tags are :-");
        MainActivity.logTags(associatedTags);
        UiModel u = new UiModel(p,associatedTags);
        Log.d("GETFLTRDMDLLST","UIModels are :-");
        MainActivity.logUiModel(u);
        resultList.add(u);
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

and the following testing code (again in MainActivity.java) :-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPDB = Room.databaseBuilder(this,PersonDatabase.class,"person.db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    addDataIfNone();
    List<Person> allPeople = mPDB.personDao().getAllPersons();
    logPersons(allPeople);
    List<Tag> allTags1 = mPDB.personDao().getAllTags();
    logTags(allTags1);
    List<PersonTagRelation> allPTRs = mPDB.personDao().getAllPersonTagRelations();
    logPersonTagRelations(allPTRs);
    List<UiModel> uiModelList = mPDB.personDao().getAllAsModelList();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().append("UIMODELS are :-");
    for (UiModel u: uiModelList) {
        sb.append("\n\tPerson ID = " + String.valueOf(u.getPerson().getPresonID()) + " Name = " + u.getPerson().getPersonName());
        for (Tag t: u.getTagList()) {
            sb.append("\n\t\tTag ID = " + String.valueOf(t.getTagID()) + " Value = " + t.getTagValue());
        }
    }
    Log.d("UIMODELINFO",sb.toString());

    List<Tag> allTags = mPDB.personDao().getAllTags();
    List<UiModel> uiListOfModelsViaFilter;
    for (Tag t: allTags) {
        Log.d("TAGFILTERINF","Filtering with a TAG value of " + t.getTagValue() );
        uiListOfModelsViaFilter = mPDB.personDao().getFilteredModelList(String.valueOf(t.getTagValue()));
        logUiModel(uiListOfModelsViaFilter);
    }
}

private void addDataIfNone() {
    List<Person> people = mPDB.personDao().getAllPersons();
    if (people.size() > 0) return;

    Person[] peopleToAdd = new Person[]{
            new Person("A"),
            new Person("B"),
            new Person("C")
    };
    mPDB.personDao().insertNewPersons(peopleToAdd);

    Tag[] tagsToAdd = new Tag[] {
            new Tag("ai"),
            new Tag("ML"),
            new Tag("Flutter"),
            new Tag("JS"),
            new Tag("Kotlin"),
            new Tag("Dart")
    };
    mPDB.personDao().insertNewTags(tagsToAdd);

    PersonTagRelation[] ptr = new PersonTagRelation[]{
            new PersonTagRelation(1,1),
            new PersonTagRelation(1,2),
            new PersonTagRelation(2,1),
            new PersonTagRelation(3,3)
    };
    mPDB.personDao().insertNewRelations(ptr);
}
```

The the more pertinent out shows that for tag **ai** that persons **A** and **B** are extracted :-

```
06-24 11:27:53.365 9889-9889/? D/TAGFILTERINF: Filtering with a TAG value of ai
06-24 11:27:53.366 9889-9889/? D/GETFLTRMDLLST: Processing TAG where value is ai ID is 1
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/GETFLTRDMDLLST: Persons are :-
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/PERSONINFO: People are :-
        Person ID is 1 Name isA
        Person ID is 2 Name isB
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/GETFLTRDMDLLST: Tags are :-
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/TAGINFO: Tags are
        Tag ID is 1 Value is ai
        Tag ID is 2 Value is ML
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/GETFLTRDMDLLST: UIModels are :-
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/UIMODELINFO: UIMODEL Person ID = 1 Person Name = A
            Tag ID =1 Value = ai
            Tag ID =2 Value = ML
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/GETFLTRDMDLLST: Persons are :-
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/PERSONINFO: People are :-
        Person ID is 1 Name isA
        Person ID is 2 Name isB
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/GETFLTRDMDLLST: Tags are :-
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/TAGINFO: Tags are
        Tag ID is 1 Value is ai
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/GETFLTRDMDLLST: UIModels are :-
06-24 11:27:53.367 9889-9889/? D/UIMODELINFO: UIMODEL Person ID = 2 Person Name = B
            Tag ID =1 Value = ai
06-24 11:27:53.369 9889-9889/? D/UIMODELINFO(LIST):     UIModel Person ID = 1 Person Name = A
            Tag ID =1 Value = ai
            Tag ID =2 Value = ML
        UIModel Person ID = 2 Person Name = B
            Tag ID =1 Value = ai
```

## Edit

This is the full PersonTagRelation class :-

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"personTagIDForPerson","personTagIDForTag"},
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(entity = Person.class, parentColumns = "presonID", childColumns = "personTagIDForPerson"),
                @ForeignKey(entity = Tag.class, parentColumns = "tagID", childColumns = "personTagIDForTag"),
        })
public class PersonTagRelation {
    private long personTagIDForPerson, personTagIDForTag;

    public PersonTagRelation() {
    }

    public PersonTagRelation(long personTagIDForPerson, long personTagIDForTag) {
        this.personTagIDForPerson = personTagIDForPerson;
        this.personTagIDForTag = personTagIDForTag;
    }

    public long getPersonTagIDForPerson() {
        return personTagIDForPerson;
    }

    public void setPersonTagIDForPerson(long personTagIDForPerson) {
        this.personTagIDForPerson = personTagIDForPerson;
    }

    public long getPersonTagIDForTag() {
        return personTagIDForTag;
    }

    public void setPersonTagIDForTag(long personTagIDForTag) {
        this.personTagIDForTag = personTagIDForTag;
    }
}
```

- Note the constructor that takes the two values (and how it is used in the **addDataIfNone** method).

Comment: I added the logcat. i am guessing that relations  entities in PersonTagRelations are not getting added correctly

Comment: @anshsachdeva you need to control how they get added (see how I add them in my code noting that I hard-code the id's (you would have to retrieve them from the respective Person/Tags)).

Comment: @anshsachdeva I've edited the answer and added the **PersonTagRelation** class, which appears to be where your issue is.

Comment: thanks but i was actually using that exact same PersonTagRelation.class. i just wrote a part of it for brevity. But on looking into `addDataIfNone` made me realize my mistake. My UI was generating a unique id for tag everytime i added a new tag! So if 2 persons are having same tag `ai`, they still don't have anything common because  the tag `ai` is having different ids for both of them  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯